# hyper-v centos machine loses internet connection when changing Wi-Fi networks

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, centos, hyper-v

I'm running CentOS 6.9 inside a Hyper-V virtual machine, using a LAMP stack with Node and Coldfusion.

When I'm in the office, connected to our Wi-Fi network everything works fine - I develop from my host Windows machine directly on the Hyper-V machine using Samba to access network drives, then I have custom hosts set to mask my virtual machine's IP, e.g. `192.168.0.15 dev.example.com` - and I can push and pull from Github via the VM's CLI

When I bring the laptop home, Windows connects to the internet and I can ping the Hyper-V machine from `cmd` and ping the host machine from the centos CLI, so it all seems fine.

I can visit `dev.example.com` in the browser on my host machine,  but I cannot access the internet, so from my dev machine I cannot push/pull to github, or even do something simple like `ping google.com`

I've tried many things to try and get it to work, changing the hyper-v network switch, bridging and unbridging different adapters on windows - I ended up completely screwing my laptop over so that Windows itself couldn't connect to the Wi-Fi either at home or the office.

So I've managed to get back to this stage:
- office, Windows connects to Wi-Fi, windows and the VM see each other, VM has internet access
- home, Windows connects to Wi-Fi, windows and the VM see each other, VM has no internet access

I feel like it must be a privacy setting set on my connection to my home network, but I don't know where to look.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to change the NIC in VM or hyperV settings?

Comment: well it still uses the same network adapter - the host windows laptop is still being used to connect to a wifi network, I just have 2 different networks